# mutiple regular expression using grepl in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

```
dat <- data.frame(tmax.p.start_d = rnorm(1),
                  tmin.p.start_d = rnorm(1),
                  rain.p.start_d = rnorm(1),

                  tmax.p.end_d = rnorm(1),
                  tmin.p.end_d = rnorm(1),
                  rain.p.end_d = rnorm(1))
```

I want to drop all columns that both `tmax` and `start` OR `tmin` and 'start' OR `rain` and `start`. So final dataframe will have only `tmax.p.end_d`, `tmin.p.end_d` and `rain.p.end_d`. The below command only works for a single pattern. Is it possible to include all the above conditions in one single expression

```
      dat[, !grepl(pattern="tmax", colnames(dat))] 
      dat[, !grepl(pattern="tmin", colnames(dat))]  
      dat[, !grepl(pattern="rain", colnames(dat))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood right, you can combine with `&` and use `|` in a pattern to act as an OR command e.g.

```
# not (start and (tmax or tmin or rain))
dat[, !(grepl(pattern="start", colnames(dat)) & 
          grepl(pattern="tmax|tmin|rain", colnames(dat)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `select_at` with `matches` from dplyr to select/drop columns based on regular expressions.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  select_at(vars(-matches('start', 'tmin|tmax|rain')))
```